# ClojureScript spec assertions not triggering exception

Tags: clojure, clojurescript, leiningen

I have a utility function that uses spec to ensure the map argument passed is fully keyed by integers:

**src/project/utils.cljs**

```
(ns project.utils
  (:require [cljs.spec.alpha :as s]))

(defn next-int-key
 "Return the next integer key for a integer keyed map."
 [m]
 (if (empty? m) 0
   (+ 1 (apply max (keys m)))))

(s/fdef next-int-key :args (s/cat :m (s/map-of int? some?)) :ret int?)
```

Passing a non-integer keyed map should trigger a spec assertion exception:

**test/project/utils_test.cljs**

```
(ns project.utils-test
  (:require [project.utils :as utils]
            [cljs.test :refer-macros [deftest testing is]]
            [cljs.spec.alpha :as s]))

(deftest test-next-int-key
  (testing "next-int-key util function"
    (testing "with an empty map"
      (is (= 0 (utils/next-int-key {}))))
    (testing "with a populated, integer keyed map"
      (is (= 4 (utils/next-int-key {0 :zero-val 1 :one-val 2 :two-val 3 :three-val}))))
    (testing "with a populated, integer keyed map that has a gap"
      (is (= 5 (utils/next-int-key {0 :zero-val 1 :one-val 2 :two-val 4 :four-val}))))
    (testing "with a non-integer keyed map"
      (is (= 5 (utils/next-int-key {:one "foo"}))))))
```

**However, no exception is triggered, instead the utility function is allowed to execute, producing a bad value.**

From Clojure's/CLJS spec documentation spec assertions are enabled by default.

I have `:global-vars {*asserts* true}` in my leiningen `project.clj`, although I believe this is the default value anyway.

Comment: Note that `s/fdef` is a development-time tool. To enforce constraints on function args/result consider using `:pre`/`:post` conditions instead, see https://clojure.org/reference/special_forms#fn.

Comment: Thanks, the reference to `:pre` and `:post` is really useful!

Answer (score 1):

You have to call `cljs.spec.test.alpha/instrument` to have your spec'd functions' invocations asserted. Calling it with no args will instrument every spec'd function that has been loaded:

```
(stest/instrument)
```

You can call this in your test namespace, optionally passing the specific symbol(s) you want to instrument:

```
(stest/instrument `utils/next-int-key)
```

Update: failed to mention some other options, like using `s/valid?` and `:pre`/`:post` assertions:

```
(defn stringer-bell
  "Prints a string and rings bell."
  [s]
  {:pre [(s/valid? (s/nilable string?) s)]}
  (println s "\007"))
```

Or using `s/assert` in your function body (remember to `(s/check-asserts [true|false])` to toggle):

```
(defn stringer-bell [s]
  (s/assert (s/nilable string?) s)
  (println s "\007"))
```

Comment: Thanks, I re-read the clojure.spec guide and I realised I needed to use `:pre` `:post` conditions to check and enforce spec at runtime.